# API to retrieve subscribers with statistics from journey in Marketing Cloud (former ExactTarget)

Tags: api, exacttarget, journey

We have following task:
In the Marketing Cloud there are few journeys created by Journey Builder. They all are assigned to different Data Extensions via Event Source.
I'm going to receive all Data Extension rows that participate in specific Journey. Also we need to retrieve basic statistics by participants that shows us actual status of participant (data extension row in journey) like: what is the current place in journey for participant (received first email, received sms in line after first email etc.).

To retrieve all participants I suspect we have to use:

```
GET /interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/{eventDefinitionId}
where eventDefinitionId is Id from 
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{journeyId}
```

please correct me if I'm wrong.

The question is if there is some API that allows to retrieve statistic data described below.

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud)  tag

Comment: Thanks Adam for advice. Recreated question there: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149277/api-to-retrieve-subscribers-with-statistics-from-journey-in-marketing-cloud-for